# Hidden text in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem which I'm pretty sure I've seen before but I could find the solution anyway.

I've built a website, http://kefwithjeff.org, and it looks not bad on Chrome and Firefox:
[image: Kef With Jeff - Chrome SS]

But, for some reason, when I open it on Internet Explorer 8, Most f the text is invisible:

[image: Kef with Jeff - IE SS]

What is causing that problem? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your font format (woff) is not supported by IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

You have to download font and add it in your CSS file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Droid Sans";
  src: url('DroidSans-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hey, you're right! 
Sorry it took me a while to test it out. 

I tried to use Google Fonts like this: 
`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700);` 
but it didn't work :(
Anyway, I just removed 'Droid Sans', since most of the site is in Hebrew anyway and Droid Sans doesn't support Hebrew. Both Hebrew and English look fine in Sans-Serif, so I'll stick with that, because it works. Thank you for telling me the source of the problem!